# Laptop randomly loses wifi connection

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

I recently upgraded my laptop from Windows 7 (Ultimate Edition) 64-bit to Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSB 64-bit (Version 10.0.14393). (I deliberately went for the 2016 LTSB edition for several reasons, mainly that it leaves out many unwanted features such as Cortana and it doesn't interrupt your work in order to install new unwanted features all the time, but just installs important security updates).

After this upgrade, I am finding that, once in a while (like every few days) the laptop disconnects from the router (a Thomson DG585). The router is still connected to the Internet (Talk Talk, based in the UK) and our other devices (mobile phones and a Linux laptop) are all still connected to it at the same time.

The laptop is an Asus X552CL with 6GB RAM, bought in 2014. Windows System Information reports the wifi card as a Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter.

After losing wifi connection, if I try to connect again from the taskbar's wifi icon, it says "Connecting" for a second and then "Not connected". If I try "Troubleshoot", it tells me there's something wrong with the router, but I know that's not the case as all the other devices are connected ok. I looked in the System Event log but didn't find anything relevant. The only way I found to reconnect my laptop is to shut it down and restart it.

Is there any other troubleshooting method or any other logs I can look at to try to resolve this problem?

Comment: I have laptop with qualcomm atheros qca9377, which is having similar issue. It is now working better, it now happens rarely. Try searching for the most recent driver version for your adapter. My next step is to put Wi-Fi adapter from another vendor.

Comment: Try to disable the power management feature of the driver (In device manager) and look through the oter options if you find something "suspicious" regarding re/connection. I guess you use the laptop most of the time as standtop, so nothing to worry. A fixed IP in your homenet also helps regarding restarting, so you need no new lease from the router. If you do not want to change this a simple deactivate/activate in network adapters enables reconnect normaly - no restart needed.

Comment: I have actually done everything you have mentioned and it didn't help. Just wanted to share my experience with OP.